# ASP classic string variable maximum size?

Tags: string, asp-classic, limit, max

Is there a limit on the size a string variable can grow in ASP classic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string variable can contain from 0 to approximately 2 billion Unicode characters.

**References:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhw1f6w5(v=vs.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Isn't this asp.net? But I should be able to find a similar reference for ASP classic from there.

Comment: @Szocske No, this is correct. It's referencing VBScript and/or JSCript which are the two scripting languages used in ASP.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.Length` property returns an `int`, so the maximum length of a string is
`Int32.MaxValue()` = **2,147,483,647** characters. Practically this will probably
mean that you can make your string as long as you have memory available to
put it in.

Comment: The question is for ASP *classic*, not ASP.NET.

Comment: I know but the real answer is still `2,147,483,647`. I don't understand why this is downvote.